# Printing formatted arbitrary precision decimals in python

Tags: python, printing, precision, arbitrary-precision

Python's arbitrary precision decimals are lovely, but I can't seem to find a way to print them in a nicely formatted way. For example, if I compute the following expression:

```
>>> pow(2,70) -2
1180591620717411303422L
```

it ends in a 2, like it should. However, if I try to format it to show two decimal places, it gets rounded to 2^70 because floats aren't very precise.

```
>>> print "{0:.2f}".format(pow(2,70) -2)
1180591620717411303424.00
```

Is there a way to print with the formatting I want without losing precision?
(and without using any non-standard modules such as NumPy)

Comment: I don't get it.  You want to print an integer with decimal places? Why?  How about `print "{}.00".format(pow(2,70) - 2)`?

Comment: decimal places are always .00 for your case?

Comment: I want to print the result of a computation with decimal places, and that computation sometimes returns fractional values. I only used an integer in the example because it was an easy number that was large enough to show the problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works for me:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> '{0:.2f}'.format(decimal.Decimal((pow(2,70)-2)))
1180591620717411303422.00
```

From the [decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) module documentation:

> The decimal module provides support for decimal floating point arithmetic. [...] 
>   Decimal numbers can be represented exactly.

Comment: I thought I tried that and it didn't work, but now it seems to be working for the most part. I still can't make it work for something like (pow(2,70) + .75), but it appears that this is a theoretical case (at least so far) and I don't need to worry about it.

Comment: @sapphiremirage In that case, you'll need to convert to `decimal` before any other operation: `decimal.Decimal(pow(2,70))+decimal.Decimal(0.75)`